# How to limit a LINQ query based on date and a secondary ID

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following table of products:

```
Id
ProductName
ProductType
IsActive
SecondaryId
```

so the records will look like:

```
ID: 1
ProductName: product1
IsActive: true
SecondaryId: 333
CreatedOn: 1/14/2020

Id: 2
ProductName: product2
IsActive: true
SecondaryId: 333
CreatedOn: 1/13/2020

Id: 3
ProductName: product3
IsActive: true
SecondaryId: 221
CreatedOn: 1/13/2020
```

and then the following query to retrieve them:

```
var products = _context.Product
    .Where(x.IsActive)
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedOn)
    .ToDTOs();
```

The SecondaryId is a field used to clone parts of the product when creating new ones.  So a user can come in, select an existing product, and then it inherits that secondaryID.  We're then using the SecondaryID to track updates to the product.  Technically, we should have had another table to do this, but I wasn't here when that decision was made.

What I'm trying to do is write the select query so that it will return all of the products in the database, but of the products with an existing SecondaryID, only return the most recent ones.  So say four products exist with the same SecondaryID, I only want the most recent one included in the list. So in my example

Newer to LINQ, but stuck.

Comment: Can you please add some data and expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var products = _context.Product
    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
    .GroupBy(x => x.SecondaryId)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).First())
    .ToDTOs();
```

Then within each group, select the object with highest `CreatedOn`.

Comment: Thank you, this got me where I needed to be

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to group by the Secondary ID's, then take only the first row from each grouping, like so:

```
var products = _context.Product
                       .Where(x => x.IsActive)
                       .GroupBy(x => x.SecondaryID)
                       .Select(x => x.OrderByDesc(y => y.CreatedOn).First())
                       .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedOn)
                       .ToDTOs();
```

EDIT: missed that you wanted specifically the newest from each grouping - the OrderByDesc in the Select statement should do the trick